# Using Gin and JobRunner

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, go-gin

I'm using [JobRunner](https://github.com/bamzi/jobrunner) for scheduler and Gin-gonic framework for my Golang project.

I have tried the package and it works. Problem is, when I would like to connect to my database, I cannot access the gin context inside the schedule function

```
func ScheduleUrl() {
   jobrunner.Start() // optional: jobrunner.Start(pool int, concurrent int) (10, 1)
   jobrunner.Schedule("@every 20s", CheckExpiredUrl{})
}

// Job Specific Functions
type CheckExpiredUrl struct {
// filtered
}


  // ReminderEmails.Run() will get triggered automatically.
func (e CheckExpiredUrl) Run() {
  // Queries the DB
  // Sends some email
  fmt.Println("Every 20 sec Check Expired Url ")

  db := c.MustGet("db").(*mgo.Database)
  urls := []models.Url{}
  err := db.C(models.CollectionUrl).Find(nil).Sort("-expired_at").All(&urls)
  if err != nil {
      c.Error(err)
  }
}
```

I need to use c *gin.Context inside jobrunner function, and how should I do that?

Comment: A `context` is defined per request, i.e. it will be created every time the server receive HTTP request. Normally it's valid only from beginning till the end of the request. So it's not a good practice to pass the context to *background job*. What information do you want from context?

Comment: i just want to get my session set from my context, any alternative way ?

Comment: One method will be: using a middleware. In the middleware, you can access `gin.Context` and extract needed information. Once you get the information, post it to *background job/task*, e.g. through channel. See [Custom Middleware](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#custom-middleware)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jobrunner.Now(NowDo{}) and pass gin context into it